# What subdomains of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ via rational functions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, real-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry

For what subdomains $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ does there exist a rational diffeomorphism $h:D \to \mathbb{R}^2_+$, such that its inverse is also a rational function? (By "rational function" I mean a ratio of two polynomials.)

For example, if $D$ is a *proper convex cone*, then we can choose $h$ to be just a *linear diffeomorphism* from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. What *other* domains $D$ are rationally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2_+$?

Comment: Aren't the only rational functions whose inverse is also rational, the projective linear ones?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch In dimension one an invertible rational map must be projective linear, but not necessarily in dimension two and higher. For example $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+f(x))$ is invertible for any rational function $f$.